# MSSQL Permissions syslogins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I was trying a simple query to list Windows Groups & their Logins.
As you can see below, my second principal appears to have no corresponding login.

However, when a sys_admin runs this exact same code, he gets 'MyLogin2Name' instead of the NULL that I see.

Does anyone know what is going on here ?
It has us both scratching our heads ! :(

```
USE myDB;
SELECT 
p.principal_id, p.[name], sl.[name]
FROM sys.database_principals p
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.syslogins sl
ON p.sid = sl.sid
WHERE p.[type] in ('G');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when a sys_admin runs this exact same code, he gets 'MyLogin2Name'

Right a sysadmin can see all the logins.  A regular user cannot.  This behavior is documented in `sys.server_principals`, which is the non-legacy view for logins:

> Permissions
>
> Any login can see their own login name, the system logins,
>   and the fixed server roles. To see other logins, requires ALTER ANY
>   LOGIN, or a permission on the login. To see user-defined server roles,
>   requires ALTER ANY SERVER ROLE, or membership in the role.
>
> The visibility of the metadata in catalog views is limited to
>   securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been
>   granted some permission. For more information, see Metadata Visibility
>   Configuration.

[sys.server_principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql)